# My Script that is a clicking game wont update local storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have been working on the script below for a while now and I am stuck. I have tried to see what is wrong and I think it is something small.

```
<form name="f1">Gold:
    <input type="text" value='0' name="t1" id="a2" disabled>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Click me!" id="a1" onclick="clickAdd">
    <br>Jewels:
    <input type="text" value="0" name="g1" id="a3" disabled>
    <br>Cost: 50 Gold
    <input type="button" value="5 jewels" id="a4" onclick="click5()">
    <br>Cost: 100 Gold
    <input type="button" value="10 jewels" id="a5" onclick="click10()">
    <br>
</form>
<script>
    function clickAdd() {
        //Detects if local stoage click count exists
    if (localStorage.getItem("clickcount") == null || NaN) {
            localStorage.setItem(clickcount, 0);
    document.getElementById("a2").value = localStorage.getItem('clickcount');
            //Sets the clickcount to zero
        } 
    else {
            //If it already exists.    
            localStorage.setItem("clickcount",localStorage.clickcount + 1);
            document.getElementById("a2").value = localStorage.getItem('clickcount');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Can someone please fix it or tell me what is wrong.

Comment: Compare the code for setting the item in the `if` and the code for setting the item in the `else`. Also your null check is a bit off.

You haven't told us your exact problem though, what does work? What doesn't work?

Comment: It wont create the localstorage itself and thats the reasons the rest wont work.

Answer (score 1):

First of all add the parens to invoke the function as follows

```
<input type="button" value="Click me!" id="a1" onclick="clickAdd()">
```

Change `"null"` to `null`.

then for updating -

```
localStorage.setItem("clickcount", parseInt(localStorage.getItem('clickcount')) + 1);;
```

and for setting the value -

```
document.getElementById("a2").value = localStorage.getItem('clickcount');
```

You should use `getItem()` and `setItem()` methods to access local storage. Check this [SO question for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

[JSfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/F5NtC/)